# SQL Server SEQUENCE is resetting itself every few days on Azure SQL.. why?

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database

Example command I am using in the query editor of Azure SQL:

```
ALTER SEQUENCE dbo.MySeqName
    RESTART WITH 5000  
    INCREMENT BY 1
```

It works fine initially, then after a few days, I check the sequence, and it has reset itself back to start at 1!

Where do I even start to troubleshoot?

**EDIT:** More info, just to point out explicitly that I don't expect it to cycle nor do I want it to cycle.

The MINVALUE is 1 and MAXVALUE = very large number i.e. Max BigInt.

**EDIT#2:** If there is some rogue or automated script that is executing and re-setting the sequence, are there history logs anywhere, or can I turn it on temporarily for, say a week to view all statements executed on Azure SQL?

Comment: Check the `CYCLE | NO CYCLE` property of your sequence object. As well as `MAXVALUE`

Comment: RESTART simply sets the current(if last used value < restart value)/start value of the sequence. From https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-sequences-transact-sql : “ When the sequence object cycles it proceeds to the minimum_value or maximum_value, not the start_value.” https://dbfiddle.uk/H4G-lBOL

Comment: My bad, I edited the question to provide more info, it wasn't obvious, I should have said my maxvalue is very large, hence no reason for it to cycle.

Comment: What is the actual, full definition of the sequence if you script it out?

Comment: You could create a database ddl trigger and log any sequence ddl changes `create table logtable(eventxml xml);` and `create trigger sequenceddllog on database for DDL_SEQUENCE_EVENTS as begin insert into logtable(eventxml) values(EVENTDATA()); end`

Answer (score 0):

I tried to replicate your issue in my environment by creating sequence with below code:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE MySeqName1
start with 1
increment by 1
minvalue 0
maxvalue 5
cycle
cache 5000;
```

Create a table and inserted values into that by using created sequence

```
CREATE TABLE students
( 
    Id int,
   Name char(20)
);

Insert into students(Id,Name) values(NEXT VALUE FOR MySeqName1, 'AA'),
                                    (NEXT VALUE FOR MySeqName1, 'BB'),
                                    (NEXT VALUE FOR MySeqName1, 'CC'),
                                    (NEXT VALUE FOR MySeqName1, 'DD'),
                                    (NEXT VALUE FOR MySeqName1, 'EE'),
                                    (NEXT VALUE FOR MySeqName1, 'FF'),
                                    (NEXT VALUE FOR MySeqName1, 'GG')

select * from students
```

[image]

I reset the sequence using below code

```
ALTER SEQUENCE dbo.MySeqName
    RESTART WITH 4  
    INCREMENT BY 1
```

Inserted values into table sequence is repeating after max value So as @Vladimir Baranov said check the  CYCLE option using below code:

```
SELECT is_cycling FROM sys.sequences WHERE name = 'MYSeqName' ;
```

[image]

So `CYCLE` is enabled for the sequence If you want to remove `CYCLE` option use below code:

```
ALTER SEQUENCE MYSeqName  
     NO CYCLE
```

After the execution of above code it is disabled

[image]

Comment: How does that answer my question, I don't expect it to cycle, I don't want it to cycle.